# jQuery append will download external src in script tags, but won't load into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, src, script-element

If I include a script with an external source and then try to parse using jQuery - it will download the script, but won't load it into the DOM.  I'm using using [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/), but this seems to be the case for any other jQuery DOM insertion method.

#### Here's an example in Stack Snippets

```js
$(function(){
  
  var selet2Html =
    '<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>' +
    '<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js" ><\/script>' +
    '<select class="select2">' +
    '  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>' +
    '  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '<script >' +
    '  $(function() {' +
    '    $(".select2").select2();' +
    '  });' +
    '<\/script>';
    
  $("body").append(selet2Html);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
```

Even though this will download the script in the network tab:

[image: Network Activity]

It will still return the following error (indicating that the external library - select2 - never loaded):

[image: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function]

I'd prefer not to use [`$.getScript()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) as I'm actually loading this string dynamically with [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/), so I'm not sure if it's going to contain any external scripts or not.

How can I get it to load the external library?

Comment: you need to give it time to load before you use it, dynamic tags are not sync like hard-coded tags

Comment: yeah, this is a simple race condition. you need to wait for `$.fn.select2` to appear.

Comment: As I know, neither `.getScript()`, nor `.load()` will tell you when your loaded script is executed. Their callbacks fires when file loaded and not necessarly executed.  I suggest you split your code to different parts that you will append `.when()` each part is `.done()`.

Comment: Have you considered using $.holdready? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/

Answer (score 0):

So dandavis is right - the library needs time to load before calling the initializer on it.  A naive implementation could just wait a short amount of time and try again like this:

```js
setTimeout( function() {
  $(".select2").select2();
}, 2000);
```

#### Simple Demo in Stack Snippets:

```js
$(function(){
  
  var selet2Html =
    '<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>' +
    '<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js" ><\/script>' +
    '<select class="select2">' +
    '  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>' +
    '  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '<script >' +
    '  setTimeout( function() {' +
    '    $(".select2").select2();' +
    '  }, 2000);' +
    '<\/script>';
   
  $("body").append(selet2Html);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
```

A more sophisticated solution would wait until `$.fn.select2` showed up in the DOM.

**Enter `OnAvailable`**

You can call it like this:

```
onAvailable('$.fn.select2', function() {
  alert('we did it');
});
```

Here's the function that will poll the global namespace for your variable to popup.  It uses Alnitak's `Object.byString` solution from [Accessing nested JavaScript objects with string key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6491621/1366033)

```
function onAvailable(listenFor, callback) {
  var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (Object.byString(window, listenFor)) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      callback()
    }
  }, 100);
};
```

#### Advanced Demo in Stack Snippets

```js
function onAvailable(listenFor, callback) {
  var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (objectFromString(window, listenFor)) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      callback()
    }
  }, 100);
};

function objectFromString(o, s) {
  s = s.replace(/\[(\w+)\]/g, '.$1'); // convert indexes to properties
  s = s.replace(/^\./, '');           // strip a leading dot
  var a = s.split('.');
  for (var i = 0, n = a.length; i < n; ++i) {
    var k = a[i];
    if (k in o) {
      o = o[k];
    } else {
      return;
    }
  }
  return o;
}

$(function(){
  
  var selet2Html =
    '<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>' +
    '<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.js" ><\/script>' +
    '<select class="select2">' +
    '  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>' +
    '  <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '<script >' +
    '  onAvailable("$.fn.select2", function() {' +
    '    $(".select2").select2();' +
    '  });' +
    '<\/script>';
   
  $("body").append(selet2Html);
  
  
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
```